# Some small and short questions about my instantiateobjects script and fly to over terrain script and how to integrate between them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The InstantiateObjects I'm generating objects in random positions random scale random rotation and also random height.

This script is attached to a GameObject name InstantiateObjects Objects

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InstantiateObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;
    public Terrain terrain;
    public float yOffset = 0.5f;
    [Range(10, 1000)]
    public int objectsAmount = 20;
    public bool randomScale = false;
    public bool randomRotation = false;
    [Range(1, 100)]
    public float spinSpeed = 50;
    public bool spinPbjects = false;
    public bool parent = true;
    public string parentName;
    public bool addNewAtStart = false;
    public Vector3 RandScaleMin;
    public Vector3 RandScaleMax;
    [Range(0, 360)]
    public float randomRotationX;
    [Range(0, 360)]
    public float randomRotationY;
    [Range(0, 360)]
    public float randomRotationZ;

    private float terrainWidth;
    private float terrainLength;
    private float xTerrainPos;
    private float zTerrainPos;
    private int oldAmount;
    private GameObject objInstance;

    void Start()
    {
        //Get terrain size
        terrainWidth = terrain.terrainData.size.x;
        terrainLength = terrain.terrainData.size.z;

        //Get terrain position
        xTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.x;
        zTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.z;

        oldAmount = objectsAmount;

        generateObjectOnTerrain();
    }

    void generateObjectOnTerrain()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsAmount; i++)
        {
            //Generate random x,z,y position on the terrain
            float randX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xTerrainPos, xTerrainPos + terrainWidth);
            float randY = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 100);
            float randZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zTerrainPos, zTerrainPos + terrainLength);

            float yVal = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(randX, 0, randZ));

            var randScaleX = Random.Range(RandScaleMin.x, RandScaleMax.x);
            var randScaleY = Random.Range(RandScaleMin.y, RandScaleMax.y);
            var randScaleZ = Random.Range(RandScaleMin.z, RandScaleMax.z);
            var randVector3 = new Vector3(randScaleX, randScaleY, randScaleZ);

            var randRotX = Random.Range(0, randomRotationX);
            var randRotY = Random.Range(0, randomRotationY);
            var randRotZ = Random.Range(0, randomRotationZ);
            var randRotation = Quaternion.Euler(randRotX, randRotY, randRotZ);

            //Apply Offset if needed
            yVal = yVal + yOffset;

            objInstance = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(randX, /*yVal*/ randY, randZ), Quaternion.identity);


            objInstance.tag = "Target";

            if (randomScale == true)
            {
                objInstance.transform.localScale = randVector3;//new Vector3(randScaleX, randScaleY, randScaleZ);
            }

            if (randomRotation == true)
            {
                objInstance.transform.rotation = randRotation;
            }

            if (parent)
            {
                if (parentName != null && parentName != "")
                {
                    GameObject parent = GameObject.Find(parentName);
                    objInstance.transform.parent = parent.transform;
                }
                else
                {
                    objInstance.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On a Camera name Fly Camera I have two attached scripts:

Fly To Over Terrain:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FlyToOverTerrain : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float desiredHeight = 10f;

    public float flightSmoothTime = 10f;
    public float maxFlightspeed = 10f;
    public float flightAcceleration = 1f;

    public float levelingSmoothTime = 0.5f;
    public float maxLevelingSpeed = 10000f;
    public float levelingAcceleration = 2f;

    private Vector3 flightVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    private float heightVelocity = 0f;

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        float currentHeight = position.y;
        if (target && flightAcceleration > float.Epsilon)
        {
            position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(position, target.position, ref flightVelocity, flightSmoothTime / flightAcceleration, maxFlightspeed, flightAcceleration * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (levelingAcceleration > float.Epsilon)
        {
            float targetHeight = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(position) + desiredHeight;

            position.y = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentHeight, targetHeight, ref heightVelocity, levelingSmoothTime / levelingAcceleration, maxLevelingSpeed, levelingAcceleration * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        transform.position = position;
    }
}
```

And the Patrol Over Terrain:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class PatrolData
{
    public Transform target = null;
    public float minDistance = 5f;
    public float lingerDuration = 5f;
    public float desiredHeight = 10f;
    public float flightSmoothTime = 10f;
    public float maxFlightspeed = 10f;
    public float flightAcceleration = 1f;
    public float levelingSmoothTime = 0.5f;
    public float maxLevelingSpeed = 10000f;
    public float levelingAcceleration = 2f;
}

public class PatrolOverTerrain : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FlyToOverTerrain flyOverTerrain;
    public LookAtCamera lookAtCamera;
    public enum PatrolMode { Clamp, Wrap, PingPong };
    public PatrolData[] patrolPoints;
    public PatrolMode mode = PatrolMode.Wrap;

    private int iterator = 0;
    private int index = 0;
    private float lingerDuration = 0f;
    private int overallLength = 0;

    public bool autoFreedomPatrol = false;
    public List<GameObject> Targets = new List<GameObject>();
    public string tagName;
    public Vector3 distanceFromTarget;

    public void Start()
    {
        if (tagName != "")
        {
            GameObject[] tempObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(tagName);

            for (int i = 0; i < tempObj.Length; i++)
            {
                //Add to list only if it does not exist
                if (!Targets.Contains(tempObj[i]))
                {
                    Targets.Add(tempObj[i]);
                }
            }

            //Get the current Size
            if (tempObj != null)
            {
                overallLength = Targets.Count;
            }

            GeneratePatrolPoints();
        }
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        if (patrolPoints.Length > 0)
        {
            lingerDuration = patrolPoints[index].lingerDuration;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        int length = patrolPoints.Length;
        if (!flyOverTerrain) return;
        if (patrolPoints.Length < 1) return;
        if (index < 0) return;

        var patrol = patrolPoints[index];
        if (lingerDuration <= 0)
        {
            iterator++;
            switch (mode)
            {
                case PatrolMode.Clamp:
                    index = (iterator >= length) ? -1 : iterator;
                    break;
                case PatrolMode.Wrap:
                    iterator = Modulus(iterator, length);
                    index = iterator;
                    break;
                case PatrolMode.PingPong:
                    index = PingPong(iterator, length);
                    break;
            }
            if (index < 0) return;

            patrol = patrolPoints[index];

            flyOverTerrain.target = patrol.target;
            flyOverTerrain.desiredHeight = patrol.desiredHeight;
            flyOverTerrain.flightSmoothTime = patrol.flightSmoothTime;
            flyOverTerrain.maxFlightspeed = patrol.maxFlightspeed;
            flyOverTerrain.flightAcceleration = patrol.flightAcceleration;
            flyOverTerrain.levelingSmoothTime = patrol.levelingSmoothTime;
            flyOverTerrain.maxLevelingSpeed = patrol.maxLevelingSpeed;
            flyOverTerrain.levelingAcceleration = patrol.levelingAcceleration;

            lookAtCamera.target = patrol.target;
            lookAtCamera.RotationSpeed = 3;

            lingerDuration = patrolPoints[index].lingerDuration;
        }

        Vector3 targetOffset = Vector3.zero;
        if ((bool)patrol.target)
        {
            targetOffset = transform.position - patrol.target.position;
        }

        float sqrDistance = patrol.minDistance * patrol.minDistance;
        if (targetOffset.sqrMagnitude <= sqrDistance)
        {
            flyOverTerrain.target = null;
            lookAtCamera.target = null;
            lingerDuration -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            flyOverTerrain.target = patrol.target;
            lookAtCamera.target = patrol.target;
        }
        distanceFromTarget = transform.position - patrol.target.position;
    }

    private int PingPong(int baseNumber, int limit)
    {
        if (limit < 2) return 0;
        return limit - Mathf.Abs(limit - Modulus(baseNumber, limit + (limit - 2)) - 1) - 1;
    }

    private int Modulus(int baseNumber, int modulus)
    {
        return (modulus == 0) ? baseNumber : baseNumber - modulus * (int)Mathf.Floor(baseNumber / (float)modulus);
    }

    public void GeneratePatrolPoints()
    {
        patrolPoints = new PatrolData[Targets.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < patrolPoints.Length; i++)
        {
            patrolPoints[i] = new PatrolData();
            patrolPoints[i].target = Targets[i].transform;
            patrolPoints[i].minDistance = 30f;
            patrolPoints[i].lingerDuration = 3f;
            patrolPoints[i].desiredHeight = 20f;
            patrolPoints[i].flightSmoothTime = 10f;
            patrolPoints[i].maxFlightspeed = 10f;
            patrolPoints[i].flightAcceleration = 3f;
            patrolPoints[i].levelingSmoothTime = 0.5f;
            patrolPoints[i].maxLevelingSpeed = 10000f;
            patrolPoints[i].levelingAcceleration = 2f;
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem that confusing me is the variable desiredHeight in the script Fly To Over Terrain. In the script Fly To Over Terrain the value of desiredHeight is 10 in the script Patrol Over Terrain in the PatrolData class the desiredHeight value is also 10 but then in the bottom inside the method GeneratePatrolPoints the value of desiredHeight is set to 20.

So there is no really effect to what value I set the desiredHeight in the Inspector of the Fly To Over Terrain script for example if I set it to 100 after the first target it will change back to 20 and then the Fly Camera will not fly to the next target.

And with the first script InstantiateObjects if I'm not generating objects in random height so maybe somehow I can get the height of the objects and set it already to the desiredHeight since all the objects generated in the same height.

But if I'm generating objects with random height ? for example between 0 and 100. What should I do with the desiredHeight then ? To set it to to the maximum height 100 ? To get the height variable from the InstantiateObjects script and set the desiredHeight to it ?

Yet the desiredHeight will be reset to 20 all the time.

So I'm a bit confused how to integrate between the scripts and the height values.

Maybe the whole thing should somehow somehow to get automatic each next target height and set each time the Desired Height to this height value of each target?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You're saying that you set the value of `desiredHeight` to 20f, but you want it to be something else? Then don't set it there.

Comment: @Eliasar No I set it to 100 in the Inspector but it's setting it back to 20. In the bottom of the script Patrol Over Terrain it's setting the Desired Height to 20. So no matter to what value I will change it in the Inspector of the script Fly To Over Terrain it will be set back to 20. I just wonder how to make it that the changing in the Fly To Over Terrain will stay with the set value and will not back to 20.

Comment: In the method GeneratePatrolPoints should I remove all the settings there for example: patrolPoints[i].desiredHeight = 20f; ? Else it will always back to value 20.

Comment: I'm not sure why there are 3 places that set the desiredHeight value.

Comment: Script will supersede the Inspector. Values that you set in the Inspector are more like initial values. You are overriding the value in script.

Comment: Ok I will make it simple. I did a test a now. In my script InstantiateObjects if I set the height of the instantiated objects to be static 10 all of them 10 then the camera will fly between them smooth as it should be. But if I set the height in the InstantiateObjects script to be random each instantiated object in a different random height then the fly camera will not fly between the objects. This is the problem I can't solve.

Comment: The problem is when the instantiated objects are not in the same height then the camera will not fly between them. If the objects all in the same height it will fly between them without a problem.

Comment: The main goal of the flying camera scripts Fly To Over Terrain and Patrol Over Terrain was to fly between objects that are on the ground.  But now I want to make that if the objects are also in the air randomly or not randomly but in the air high the camera will fly between them too.